# Eclipse CDT - how to run compiled .exe in external console (cmd.exe)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows, cmd

Is there a way to run compiled CDT program inside Eclipse IDE, but not in Eclipse terminal, but rather in new cmd.exe window? Some Run configuration or External Tools configuration?
Just like in QT, when you run compiled console application.
I googled this, on my mind, simple question, but (what is strange for me) I didn't find the answer.

Comment: You do it the same way as with any other program. Start `cmd.exe`, `cd` into the output directory where the `.exe` is located, type in the name of the executable, press ENTER.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Is this a joke? I mean, set up Eclipse, press "Run", and the program starts automatically in separate console window, not doing it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Eclipse CDT forum, from `Mr Klaus`:

Edit the Run Configuration:

On the Main page set C/C++ Application to:

```
${system_path:cmd.exe}
```

On the Arguments page add (adjust path and program name):

```
/C "start .\Debug\hello.exe"
```

On the Common page untick `"Allocate console"`.

In the example above the console windows will close immediately if hello.exe ends. If you don't want that, use this version on the Arguments page:

```
/C "start ${system_path:cmd.exe} /K .\Debug\hello.exe"
```

Btw, you could use the same concept for External Tools configuration also!

Comment: Where is "the main page"? Btw where do i have to put that string: ${system_path:cmd.exe}

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was need to change arguments:

```
/C "start /WAIT .\Debug\hello.exe"
```